# Docker : restrict host paths that can be bound as volumes

Tags: docker

I am looking for a way to restrict the host paths that can be used as volumes by the Docker daemon when running a container.

Context : the IT service in my company is divided into 2 units, the infrastructure unit and the app development unit. The former is currently introducing Linux servers as available servers to the app development unit for their deployments. The app development unit wants to use Docker for its deployments, which by default needs to be installed as root. It has been agreed that the infrastructure unit would be responsible for maintaining the server and would not provide root access to the application unit members. Instead, they would install docker on the server and grant usage of the docker command line tool to the application unit members so that they can interact with the Docker daemon and start containers.

The issue with this setup is that app development unit members could still temper with the host root owned files by binding a volume to them and using the root user from inside the container to modify / delete them. Of course they don't intend to, but since the infrastructure unit is responsible for maintaining the server, they don't want to risk it.

I looked for ways to prevent this and I found 2, namely user namespaces and Docker rootless install. But I also read that both prevent the use of the host networking mode which allows the container to use the host NET namespace, which is a requirement for the app development unit for performance reasons.

A simple solution to this would be a way to restrict the host paths the Docker Daemon is allowed to bind volumes to, but I couldn't find a way to achieve that.

Does anyone knows of one ? Or of an alternative way to meet both units requirements ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think this can be restricted.  If the only problem you're running into with a rootless setup is that host networking doesn't work, the vast majority of containers don't require host networking, even in a developer-oriented flow.

Comment: Access to the socket of the socket engine running as root on the host, is access to root on the host. You would either need rootless as David mentions, or to not give direct access to docker.

Comment: Ok too bad... I guess they will have to reach a compromise then. Thanks to the both of you for your insight.